# Save the dropdowns value when reloading the page?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have developed a [website](http://sysandersson.azurewebsites.net/material.aspx) in ASP.NET that can add articles into a another table that shows a product.

I have a table that displays items in a warehouse and a table showing the materials required to produce a certain product. Using a drop down list you can see which products are manufactured. When the user wants to add to the article, he pushes a button. But after the page loaded on my dropdown list shows the lowest value again instead of keeping its value. Visit the site, change the product (produkt in swedish) from "Cykel" (bicycle) to "car" and add any article and you will understand the problem. Can I do something with page load to find a solution?

**Maybe I should mention that I use a datasource that I'm binding the dropdown with.**

Comment: Can you save the user added options to a database and reload them from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from the gentlemen above I find out to solve the problem. I used function that is called every time the dropdownlist index is changed. The function save the index in a session.

```
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {


            try
            {
                string test = (string)Session["test"];
                int value = int.Parse(test);

                DropDownList2.SelectedIndex = value;
            }
            catch
            {
            }

        }


 protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Session["test"] = ""+ DropDownList2.SelectedIndex;

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are binding your dropdown in pageload bind it in `!ispostback`..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
          //Bind your dropdown
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you add some more details please?

Comment: @DeveloperDahak, just do your binding to dropdown only when page loads first time and not in every postback.

Comment: Thanks for the lead. I used a session to save the value every time I changed the index.

Answer (score 1):

in onChange of drop down call a function, Assume that is storeValue() function and do somthing like this, [you can add attribute to dropdown as onchange="storeValue(this.value);"]

```
function storeValue(val)
{
   localStorage.setItem("dropdownvalue",val);
}
```

and

```
var val="";
$(document).ready(function(){
       val=localStorage.getItem("dropdownvalue");
       //assign your value to dropdown list from here...
 });
```

Comment: onChange? Can't find a event that is called onChange.

Comment: I personally use onChange on <select> tag and I have done this thing before this,